# Spring alternative to Rails Paperclip

Tags: java, spring

I am working with a Spring project that has a user `@Entity` which is saved to the database via `JPARepository`.

The user also has a userimage, which we want to save to S3.
The best way I came up with was using `spring-content-s3-boot-starter` and use a `ContentRepository`. What I do not like about this approach is that the file is not handled transparently. When creating or deleting a user the `ContentRepository` always has to be involed to CRUD the respective image.

Paperclip for ActiveRecord in Rails handles this transparently, you decplare the image as attachment (`Attachment<File>`, so to say) and the DB tables and logic for the Storage Backend (S3 in this case) are done in the background when working with the repository methods on the model. Is there anything like this for Java/Spring?

Cheers

Comment: I have the same problem while trying to port and application that uses Rails and paperclip to Spring Boot and Angular. Ideally, the solution uses the same columns in the database and the same layout in the filesystem.